# Spring: PathMatcher to split variables

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I read that Spring Boot 5.3 has now a some fancy [PathPatterns](https://spring.io/blog/2020/06/30/url-matching-with-pathpattern-in-spring-mvc) but I have no clue how to use them for my requirement. I have requests like the following and want to have them filled into variables

```
/test/12-34-89_88 ==> docId=12, chapId=34, listOfSubItems= 89_88
/test/12-34-90    ==> docId=12, chapId=34, listOfSubItems= 90
/test/12-34       ==> docId=12, chapId=34, listOfSubItems= null (or "")
```

For the first two I can match with e.g.

```
@GeMappting(value="/test/{docId}-{chapId}-{listOfSubItems}
public ResponseEntity<String> getDoc(
            @PathVariable("docId") final Integer docId,
            @PathVariable("chapId") final Integer chapId,
            @PathVariable(name = "listOfSubItems", required = false) final String listOfSubItems)
```

but this fails with the third case. Is there any 'simple' Pattern which I could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add two patterns to the same endpoint.

```java
@RestController
public class TestController {
    
    @GetMapping({
            "/test/{docId:\\d+}-{chapId:\\d+}-{listOfSubItems:[_0-9]+}",
            "/test/{docId:\\d+}-{chapId:\\d+}"}
            )
    public ResponseEntity<String> getDoc(
            @PathVariable("docId") final Integer docId,
            @PathVariable("chapId") final Integer chapId,
            @PathVariable(name = "listOfSubItems", required = false) final String listOfSubItems){

        return ResponseEntity.ok("docId: "+docId+" chapId: "+chapId+" listOfSubItems: "+listOfSubItems);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I do so as recommended than I get always the exception that `listOfSubItems` for case 3. So, the proposal doesn't really help - although I thought its promissing.

Comment: I tested this and it works in all your cases. What exception do you receive?

Comment: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/3339076/95337042-1984b980-08ba-11eb-912e-e3731c73b563.png
I double-checked your cases and provided the whole controller's class code. I guess your issues somewhere else

Comment: No, the **IMPORTANT** part is that the `required` needs to be set to `false`. Otherwise Spring complains always about the missing parameter (which makes sense!). What a pity that I didn't follow my original code :-/ THX anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call endpoint "/test/12-34-" instead of "/test/12-34" because "-" in the path is necessary in this case

Comment: Yeah, but this was my request to avoid that kind of additional `"-"`